# using "optim" in case of joint density of five density function

Tags: r

I was trying to maximize a joint density function which consists five density. all densities are normal. but it gives the result, where the estimates of parameters are the initial values what I have given inside the optim function. Here is my main code:

```
like<-function(y_11,y_12,y_13,y_14,y_15,Par){

BETA_01<-Par[1]

BETA_11<-Par[2]

SIGMA_BETA1<-Par[3]

SIGMA_1<-Par[4]

FI<-Par[5]



L<--prod(dnorm(y_11,BETA_01+BETA_11+rnorm(1,0,SIGMA_BETA1),SIGMA_1)*dnorm(y_12,BETA_01+2*BETA_11+rnorm(1,0,SIGMA_BETA1)+FI*y_11,sqrt((1-FI^2)*SIGMA_1))
*dnorm(y_13,BETA_01+3*BETA_11+rnorm(1,0,SIGMA_BETA1)+FI*y_12,sqrt((1-FI^2)*SIGMA_1))*dnorm(y_14,BETA_01+4*BETA_11+rnorm(1,0,SIGMA_BETA1)+FI*y_13,sqrt((1-FI^2)*SIGMA_1))*dnorm(y_15,BETA_01+5*BETA_11+rnorm(1,0,SIGMA_BETA1)+FI*y_14,sqrt((1-FI^2)*SIGMA_1)))

}


Max<-optim(c(0.05,0.95,0.95,0.96,0.45),like,y_11=y_11,y_12=y_12,y_13=y_13,y_14=y_14,y_15=y_15)
```

I have checked a simple one, which works well. Here it is:

```
Lik<-function(H,G,lam){

mu1<-lam[1]
sig1<-lam[2]
mu2<-lam[3]
sig2<-lam[4]

L<--prod(dnorm(H,mu1+mu2,sig1+sig2^2)*dnorm(G,mu2,sig2))

}

max<-optim(c(3,0.95,0.5,0.1),Lik,H=H,G=G)
```

Can anyone please help me?

I figured out what is the problem, optim function gives the initial value as the parameter estimate, if your data is generated from any random generation process, like rnorm, rpois etc. But I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Your likelihood functions don't take `par` as their first argument; instead, you have y_11, y_12, etc. See `?optim`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason. I have edited my code, but it still gives the same result.

Comment: It's almost impossible to help unless you show us what values `y_11` to `y_15` take on.

Comment: My data is pretty big, so I could not post it here, however, i don't think its about data, there is something wrong with my code.Data is a simple normally distributed data.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for `optim` is

```
optim(par, fn, gr = NULL, ...,
      method = c("Nelder-Mead", "BFGS", "CG", "L-BFGS-B", "SANN", "Brent"),
      lower = -Inf, upper = Inf,
      control = list(), hessian = FALSE)
```

and the help file says

`fn` A function to be minimized (or maximized), with first argument the vector of parameters over which minimization is to take place. It should return a scalar result.

So you should put `Par` as the first argument in the `like` function.

```
> like <- function(Par, y_11, y_12, y_13, y_14, y_15) {
+   BETA_01 <- Par[1]
+   BETA_11 <- Par[2]
+   SIGMA_BETA1 <- Par[3]
+   SIGMA_1 <- Par[4]
+   FI <- Par[5]
+   L <- -prod(dnorm(y_11, BETA_01 + BETA_11 + rnorm(1, 0, SIGMA_BETA1), SIGMA_1) * dnorm(y_12, BETA_01 + 2 * BETA_11 + rnorm(1, 0, SIGMA_BETA1) + FI * y_11, sqrt((1 - FI^2) * SIGMA_1)) * dnorm(y_13, BETA_01 + 3 * BETA_11 + rnorm(1, 0, SIGMA_BETA1) + FI * y_12, sqrt((1 - FI^2) * SIGMA_1)) * dnorm(y_14, BETA_01 + 4 * BETA_11 + rnorm(1, 0, SIGMA_BETA1) + FI * y_13, sqrt((1 - FI^2) * SIGMA_1)) * dnorm(y_15, BETA_01 + 5 * BETA_11 + rnorm(1, 0, SIGMA_BETA1) + FI * y_14, sqrt((1 - FI^2) * SIGMA_1)))
+   return(L)
+ }
> 
> y_11 <- 5
> y_12 <- 6
> y_13 <- 7
> y_14 <- 8
> y_15 <- 9
> 
> set.seed(1)
> Max <- optim(c(0.05, 0.95, 0.95, 0.96, 0.45), like, y_11 = y_11, y_12 = y_12, y_13 = y_13, y_14 = y_14, y_15 = y_15)
> Max
$par
[1] 0.0165776 0.9866576 0.9866576 0.9966576 0.4956336

$value
[1] -0.001973574

$counts
function gradient 
     501       NA 

$convergence
[1] 1

$message
NULL
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Patrick. I have tried according to your suggestion, but it still gives the same result.

Comment: @FahmidaYeasmin What do you mean the same result? Could you get the estimate in Max?

Comment: Same result means,this code gives me the initial values what I have provided inside the optim command. Thanks

Comment: That means as an estimate of parameters I am getting the initial values of parameters what I have fixed initially